# why is an injected property with the @Inject decorator not available as this.injected_property

Tags: angular, code-injection

I have a component class called foo whose constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) catData: CatModel,
    protected catService: MeowMeow
)
```

Why is this.catService a property I can console.log and this.catData undefined?

Comment: Please include an [mcve], I strongly recommend using https://stackblitz.com. Include the link in your question.

Comment: Is `foo` being sent an input value? `<foo [MAT_DIALOG_DATA]="value">`? If not then it truly is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this instead:

constructor(@Inject(CatModel) private _catModel) { }

*Assuming is CatModel is an @Injectable